# Benefit of byte, short type

Tags: java, bytecode

The minimum slot size of an operand stack and local variable table slot size is 'int'.

Then how are we getting the benefit of declaring variable as short, byte etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `new byte[SIZE]` is going to take 1/4th the size of a `new int[SIZE]`, and when the JVM lays out a class' layout (that is, its in-memory representation, given the fields it needs to store), it can similarly compact them.

As JB Nizet points out, there's also a *semantic* concern. A lot of operations fundamentally work on bytes (reading binary files, reading from sockets, encryption, etc). In those cases, a type of `byte` clearly indicates that you're working on a byte; otherwise, you have to either check that the high 24 bits are unset (and throw a runtime exception if they're not), or else drop them and leave users of your library wondering why 256, 512, -2816 and a whole lot of other numbers all seem to yield the same result.

Comment: Thnx.  I understood it in this way "It will store as byte/short and save the memory even though it will process/operate as an int by jvm".  Am I correct?

Comment: @nantitv Yup, pretty much. (And even ints might be processed as longs, on 64-bit machines!)

Comment: @nantitv if you copy a `byte[]` to another it can copy 8 bytes at a time by treating it as an long.  This makes it up to 8x faster than if they were `long` instead of bytes.

Comment: It’s the formal specification that mandates treating `byte`, `short` and `char` as `int`, however, a specific implementation can still utilize native instructions working on `byte` and `short` as long as the result fulfills the specification, e.g. when you say `byteVariable=(byte)otherByteVariable+5;`, the bytecode will use the same `iadd` instruction as in `intVariable=otherIntVariable+5;` but a JVM may still recognize that a native byte addition is sufficient in the first case. Of course, it depends on the particular CPU whether this has a benefit and that will drive the optimizer’s decision